# Dynamics AX 2009 Load balancer AOS not showing in Online User's Server Instances form

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

Navigating to: `Administration` > `Common Forms` > `Online users` > `Server Instances`, you can see a list of all AOSes currently running.

With our dedicated load balancers, sometimes they show up here with status `Alive`, sometimes with status `Dead`, and sometimes not at all (despite the AOS's windows service running, and all appearing to be working correctly).

Is this expected behaviour, or is there something I could do to determine why this is occurring / what the impacts are?

Answer (score 0):

Solution given here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/01/11/ax-aos-server-acting-as-load-balancer-appears-with-a-status-dead-in-the-online-users-form/

Dedicated load balancers never have user sessions against them, so show in the `Server Instances` form as detailed below (more information on why this occurs is available on the above link).

- When the AOS is freshly started it will show as status `Alive`
- After 10 minutes the AOS will show as status `Dead`
- After 6 hours the AOS will disappear.

In all of these cases the AOS is working correctly / there is no impact and no action required.  It's just frustrating that you can't tell from this whether your dedicated load balancer AOS is running, but will instead have to check its Windows service status for that information.